# iTunes Autoingestion looping for a retry until successful

Tags: bash, if-statement, while-loop, app-store-connect

Hello! Right now my script below works but not quite in the way I wanted. First, I had to do a "set +e" for a block of code otherwise the script will just quit at the first error.

Sometimes, their report is not ready when my script runs. Therefore, there will be no file(s) to move from to the $temp_dir directory. This is an Exit Status 1 error.

How then can I make the script to behave like the following:

On exit status 1 (or if file does not exist whichever is the better error catching premise), wait/sleep 20 minutes then try to download the report again and move it to $temp_dir directory.

When exit status is 0 (successful) or file exists, move to the $temp_dir directory, and continue with the rest of the script. I guess this is where it will break away from the loop.

Maximum retry is 5 times, with each a 20 minutes. If maximum retry reached, exit the loop and exit the script, then return error or send email notification of error.

```
#! /bin/bash
...

set +e
java Autoingestion autoingestion.properties ${VENDOR_ID} Sales Daily Summary ${REPORT_DATE}
mv ${BASE_FILENAME} ${temp_dir}

# File or directory not found from moving, so exit status should be 1.
echo "Exit status " $?
while [[ $? -ne 0 ]] & [[ ${RETRY} -lt 6 ]]; do
    sleep 1200
    printf "\n"
    echo "Retrying download attempt #${RETRY} out of 5"
    java Autoingestion autoingestion.properties ${VENDOR_ID} Sales Daily Summary ${REPORT_DATE}
    mv ${BASE_FILENAME} ${temp_dir}
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
            echo "Download retry successful!"
            mv ${BASE_FILENAME} ${temp_dir}
            break; # Skip entire loop
    fi
    let RETRY=RETRY+1
done
set -e
printf "\n"
```

Basically, this is an attempt to say 'if failed for the first attempt, wait for 20 minutes and try again (up to 5 times). 
Your input is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be the solution:

```
while [ $counter -lt 11 ]; do
download the report
if [ -f $BASE_FILENAME ]; then
    break;
else 
    echo "Report unavailable. Retrying in 20 minutes"
    increase counter value by 1
fi
done
```